# How to change ruler size in vim?

Tags: vim

So I'm a noob to vim, and this is the default ruler line:

```
<file-name>                              line_num,col_num        %file
```

I am using tmux with 8 panes and the ruler doesn't fit on the smaller screens, so I was trying to make my own, like so:

```
:set rulerformat=%t,%l,%c
```

and the result is all jammed to the right and looks like

```
<ons.yml,314,5
```

How can I make it display the full filename? There's 59 cols available, but it's only using just like 10-15. I did try to RTFM but holy shit it's like they tried to make it as complicated as possible.

Comment: `:help 'statusline'`.

Comment: @romainl I guess we should just get rid of teachers in schools and instead have students learn directly from textbooks, since after all the material can be found in the textbook

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the command in

```
%<num>(
```

and

```
%)
```

such that it goes from

```
:set rulerformat=%t
```

to

```
:set rulerformat=%59(%t%)
```

replace  with desired width in character widths, in my case it was 59